# What does cv2.approxPolydp() return?

Tags: python, opencv, crop, contour

I am trying to resize an image according to the contour detected after applying `cv2.approxPolyDP()` . Afterwards, I have to custom crop it using `cv2.resize()` with dimensions for cropping according to the return values of the contour detected by the `cv2.approxPolyDP()`.

I want to know which **index is the height and which index is the width** or **the starting x,y coordinates and the ending x,y coordinates.**

```
def biggestContour(contours):
    biggest = np.array([])
    max_area = 0
    for i in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(i)
        if area > 5000:
            peri = cv2.arcLength(i, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(i, 0.02 * peri, True)
            if area > max_area and len(approx) == 4:
                biggest = approx
                max_area = area
    return biggest,max_area
```

Considering this code, how do I find which index is the height and which is the width or the starting x,y coordinates and the ending x,y coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cv2.approxPolyDP` returns a resampled contour, so this will still return a set of `(x, y)` points.  If you want to crop out this result, the returned contour should be a `N x 1 x 2` NumPy array, so remove the singleton dimension, then do standard min/max operations on the x and y coordinates to get the top left and bottom right corners and finally crop.  Assuming your image to crop is called `img` and your list of contours calculated from `cv2.findContours` is called `contours`, try:

```py
# Find biggest contour
cnt, area = biggestContour(contours)

# Remove singleton dimensions
points = np.squeeze(cnt)

# Extract rows and columns
y = points[:, 0]
x = points[:, 1]

# Now crop
(topy, topx) = (np.min(y), np.min(x))
(bottomy, bottomx) = (np.max(y), np.max(x))
out = img[topy:bottomy+1, topx:bottomx+1]
```

`out` will now contain the cropped image.

Comment: updated the question a bit check out the code and regarding the question on why I want the cropping is because the image is supposed to go through an OCR and there If I change dimensions of the picture the results are ruined.

Comment: OK, then all you have to do is run the code I have above on the `biggest` part of your output function.  I've edited my answer to reflect this.