# CV2.approxPolyDP Function Returns an N x 1 x 2 Array Rather Than N x 2

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a function that draws a polygon around some primary features in images by making use of OpenCV's contour detection. I simplify these contours using the approxPolyDP function in the snippet below to return a closed trapezoid around the regions, and it works fine:

`top_poly = cv.approxPolyDP(top_cnt, 0.05 * top_perimeter, closed=True)`

`top_poly = np.squeeze(top_poly)  # get rid of the singleton dimension`

However, the approxPolyDP returns a strange type of ndarray which has a shape of N x 1 x 2, when the expected output according to the documentation linked below is an array of N x 2D points (N x 2). I had to debug for a while until I found that singleton dimension in there can be carved out using np.squeeze in the second line of the snippet. Thanks to this answer: [What does cv2.approxPolydp() return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65200011/what-does-cv2-approxpolydp-return)

My question is, what is the purpose of this singleton dimension? I worry I might be dropping some useful information and I don't enjoy having to use np.squeeze() in a way I don't completely understand. Thanks for any input that can shed some light on this.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga0012a5fdaea70b8a9970165d98722b4c

Comment: it only outputs a list of points: as long as you have a list of points (with x and y coordinates) you are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result shape happens because of OpenCV's requirements, i.e. it has to map numpy arrays to `cv::Mat` and back.

A `cv::Mat` is a 2D thing with *channels*, which can be color (RGB or whatever), 2D points, 3D points, 4D, ..., or any other purpose.

The shape is generally `(height, width, channels)`.

OpenCV returns the points as a column vector (Nx1) of 2-channel data, hence `(N, 1, 2)`.

OpenCV is somewhat tolerant of different shapes like `(N, 2, 1)` which is `(N, 2)` (N rows, 2 columns, single-channel).

Comment: That makes sense now - thank you for the info! I was worried it might be some relevant data to the operation, but I get what you mean here.